# Select relevant informations from a webpage?

Tags: java, html, jsoup, article

I have to make a program which allows me to get some relevant informations from articles posted on the internet, with the URL of the article. More precisely, I have to get :
- Title
- Publication date
- Text of the article

I use the Java library jsoup, with what the program can extract HTML, and get those precious informations.

The problem is that those articles aren't stored in a single website, and every website has a different structure ! 
The title isn't really a problem, I can use this code to get the head title, which is almost every time relevant :

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://news.com/article1").get();
String title = doc.getTitle();
```

Here is an example of 2 articles :
http://www.telegraph.co.uk/finance/economics/11520066/Markets-spooked-by-threat-of-Labour-SNP-coalition-economists-warn.html

http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2015/04/06/california-drinking-water_n_7011528.html

You can see that their structure is completely different when it's about grabbing date and the entire article. So for now I have to adapt my program to every website which contains articles, and I'm wasting a lot of time !

Have you got any idea in how I can improve the program so he is able to "detect" the text of the article, and suppress irrelevant informations (like comments, related articles...) ?

**EDIT** : I also know C, PHP, some notions on Javascript and less on Python, if you know a better way to do the job than in Java... ^^

Comment: You might be better off consuming the RSS feeds of various websites rather than trying to scrape pages. RSS feeds are formatted XML feeds that you can easily consume and parse. Most news websites offer RSS feeds: http://www.telegraph.co.uk/rssfeeds/ or for a specific example, view-source:http://www.telegraph.co.uk/finance/economics/rss

Comment: Writing an algorithm to get the relevant content from a webpage will be _hard_.  [Boilerpipe](https://code.google.com/p/boilerpipe/) is an example of such an alogarithm.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm going to test Boilerpipe, it seems very promising !